# QML: SplineSeries without ChartView

Tags: qml, spline

Is it possible to draw a `SplineSeries` like in this [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtcharts-splineseries.html), but there'd be just the spline, no other components of the chart view (axis, background etc.)? Or do I have to use canvas or something similar? In that case what would be the best possibility here? I have my x, y values, so if I just could place the SplineSeries itself to my layout like this, but that's probably not possible:

```
ColumnLayout {
    SplineSeries {
            name: "spline"
            XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0.0 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 3.2 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.9; y: 2.4 }
            XYPoint { x: 2.1; y: 2.1 }
    }
}
```

Comment: SplineSeries is not a graphic element so it has no dimensions, and by itself it does not show anything, chartview is the graphical element that takes the information of the series and draws them, therefore you understand that the series to be shown must have a chartview

Comment: What a problem to use `ChartView`? If you have any reason not to use `ChartView` you can use `Canvas` to paint whatever you want as an alternative.